# Storing multi color text using a file in android

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an android project which allows user to write text using different colors and store them for later use(i.e., editing or reading).

**Is their any way to store a file in android with multi color text ??**

NOTE: I googled out for the solution but can't find anything useful.

Comment: you can use HTML `<font>` tag for that. TextView works fine with it using `HTML.fromHTML()` method

Comment: Thank you for the response. But i am using EditText with inputtype="textMultiLine". Can you tell me any way to convert this text into HTML text with tags ??

Answer (score 0):

A commenter suggested HTML, and that may be a good choice. You are welcome to try `Html.fromHtml()` to populate your `EditText` with the contents of a simple HTML-formatted file, and you are welcome to try `Html.toHtml()` to generate HTML from the contents of your `EditText`. However, historically, those methods were not written to do a good job of implementing a "round trip", meaning that the contents of the `EditText` may wind up changing from its starting point to what it contains after doing `Html.toHtml()` (to generate and save the HTML) and `Html.fromHtml()` (to populate the `EditText` with the previously-saved HTML). If they do not work, you can either fork that `Html` class and try to modify it as needed, or write your own code to take a `Spanned` object and convert it to/from HTML, by examining the spans and generating HTML tags from them.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do so. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the user has to perform some action to switch color?
If so - you can use that trigger to store the text position/length when switching and save a list of text position - color.

Comment: I was also thinking about this solution but it will be quite complicated as user can also edit the previously written text with some other color.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Code for storing a multi color text from EditText to a txt file:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    boolean writing_allowed= ExternalStorageWriting.isWritingPossible();
    if(writing_allowed)
    {
        String store= Html.toHtml(et.getEditableText());
        File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename3);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
            fos.write(store.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Notes.this, "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for reading that txt file and displaying it in EditText :

```
private void setNotes()
{
    String myData="";
    try {
        File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename3);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            myData = myData + strLine;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(myData);
    et.setText(htmlText);
}
```